# How to fetch data from a server by giving a specific request using node.js with request and response in tabular format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database, api

I have attached the problem statement and all the things required that I need to do so if someone can help that how to write code for this as I have tried a lot to do this used many approaches. please help as this is important for me to complete and now I have just 1 day left .

Problem Statement
As a user of UPI feature of One Application, one must have the functionality of viewing the
transaction history of all transactions processed on the application as well as view the details of each transaction by clicking on the tile of each such transaction .I need to create the following screen –
• Transaction History Screen – The transaction history screen lists all the transactions of a user
on UPI ecosystem done via that application. The list of transactions is populated like a chat
screen (bottom to top) with the most recent transaction appearing at the bottom. Transactions
should be grouped by the dates of transaction a
I'm using a basic fetch to obtain data from the given url server url={https://dev.onebanc.ai/assignment.asmx} that queries the data from a database by giving input.
this is the fetch function I wrote to get the desired response. [![Response[[image: ][1][1]1][image: problem statement]

```
const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ userId: 1, recipientId: 2 }),
        };
        fetch('https://dev.onebanc.ai/assignment.asmx', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => { console.log(data) })
```

Comment: Note that you can only `@mention` people who have interacted with the question before. For instance, before I wrote this comment, using @HereticMonkey would not have alerted me.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok I will remember this. please help me with this problem .